# Parsing Billing Address

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, pdf, billing-address

I am having a little trouble with `Magento's invoice PDF.` Specifically, I want to change the address formatting. For example, currently Magento outputs names and addresses under the Billing Address heading like this:

```
John Doe  
123 Fake Street Los Angeles,  
California, 90210  
T: (310) 555-5555
```

I want the output to have the following format:

```
John Doe  
123 Fake Street  
Los Angeles, California, 90210  
T: (310) 555-5555
```

Where the city is on the same line as the State and Zip.

I have found how Magento formats the first example. I am trying to figure out how to `modify Magento's code so that I get the second output.`

In **/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/ -> Abstract.php** there is a function **_formatAddress()** that takes in a string with the that looks like:

**"John Doe| 123 Fake Street Los Angeles,| California, 90210| T: (310) 555-5555"**

and parses the string with respect to the vertical bars ("|"). I've noticed that I need to place a vertical bar right after the Street in order to produce my desired output but I don't know what function inserts these vertical bars.

Also, **_formatAddress()** gets called like this:

**$billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getBillingAddress()->format('pdf'));**

I have tried tracing the **getBillingAddress()** and **format('pdf')** but have had no luck.

Does anyone know where the vertical bars get inserted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customise the format via the back-end under `System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Address Templates > Pdf`

see below 
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I moved the pipe from after "{{if city}}{{var city}}," to right before it. Thanks guys much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is the file you are looking for
`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml`

around line 562,

```
<pdf><![CDATA[{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend company}}{{var company}}|{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}
{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}|{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},|{{/if}}
{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}|
{{var country}}|
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}|]]></pdf>
```

Notice the pipes in it.

It's not recommended to edit it directly there as it's core file, you can edit it in your own module `config.xml`, something like this:

```
<default>
    <customer>
        <address_templates>
            <pdf><![CDATA[{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend company}}{{var company}}|{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}
{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}|{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},|{{/if}}
{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}|
{{var country}}|
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}|]]></pdf>
        </address_templates>
    </customer>
</default>
```